# changing text on textview with button's onClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

Hi I'm working at my first bigger app in android studio "FlashCards". I would like it to work so after you click on the button the flashcard's textview changes its text to next random flashcard untill you see all of the them how can i do something like 'continue' to my loop from inside onClick method.

here's the loop's code:

```
    while(i < mTestDeck.size()) {

        // generates random number which will represent position in deck.

        int random = randomGenerator.nextInt() % mTestDeck.size();

        // if random flashcard was already shown create random number again

        if (mTestDeck.get(random).wasShown())
            continue;

        //text view that we will operate on

        TextView deckTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.flashcard_text_view);

        // set text
        deckTextView.setText(mTestDeck.get(random).getFront());

        // set mWasShown to true

        mTestDeck.get(random).flashcardShown();

        Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.know_answer);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mTestDeck.correctAnswer();
            }
        });

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dont_know_answer);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this way, you have a potential infinite loop. And if it can happens, it will happens! It's not a good idea to "get random item and check if it's ok or try again".

I think that it's better to keep a list with all items in a random order. You just have to iterate over it.

Something like:

```
int currentPosition = 0;
List<Card> items = new ArrayList<Card>(mTestDeck).shuffle();

// Call this method once in onCreate or anywhere you initialize the UI
private void function setCurrentCard() {
    Card currentItem = items.get(currentPosition);

    [...] // Set all UI views here

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (currentPosition > items.size) {
                // TODO? End?
                return;
            }

            currentPosition++;
            setCurrentCard();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: will onClick have access to currentPosition as long as its not declared as final?

Comment: Yes, because under the hood, it call `this.currentPosition` where `this` is the outer class and is final... The anonyme object capture the outer instance class.

Comment: your idea is much better then my earlier one although when i launch my app and try to send intent to this class it shuts down and i have no idea why (i've made activity in manifes) here's the whole code: [link](https://pastebin.com/fcbgC0Dj)FlashCardsDeck is my own class which works simillary as ArrayList so you can treat it as that (it has some bonus flashcard logic but its not used yet in this code) have i made any obvious mistake that I dont see here?

Comment: Before I check, please check the logcat for the exception when your app crashed.

Comment: I've fixed that issue it was out of bounds exception i used i++ instead of i-- in shuffle algorithm.I faced another issue i want the app to behave so after you press "I don't know" button it would show you correct answer andafter 5secs it will set another card with setCurrentCard(); I've tried using handler and timer i've read that timer is better in my case (is it true tho?), anyway after using timer and pressing that button after 4 secs it closes this activity and comes back to main activity (dead activity has timer-0 exception) shpild I use this method: runOnUiThread ?

Comment: Post a new question please ;)